# Placement of conditional elements using JSON form schemas

Tags: reactjs, jsonschema

I'm tinkering around with Mozillas JSON webform tool `react-jsonschema-form` [1] and struggling to define the placement of conditional cells.

Consider a simple form with the flow:

```
|- item1 
|---conditionalitem
|- item2
```

What I want to do, is use JSON schema to create conditional logic to render some intermediary commponent if some condition satisfies. I have done this and created a little demo to see [2]. Using this logic, a secondary component will get rendered if the option selected in the first select component is `option2`.

What I would like however, is the conditional component to render between `item1` and `item2`. This can be achieved by appending `item2` inside the `dependency` object but I want `item2` to render regardless of any conditional logic. How would one achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

[1] https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form 
 
[2] https://codesandbox.io/s/red-fast-x9q0c?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can control the order in which the items get rendered. This is configurable in your `uiSchema`. Just add the below line in your `uiSchema`

```
"ui:order": ["item1", "item2","item1conditional"]
```

So the uiSchema in your App.js will become

```
const uiSchema = {
 "ui:order": ["item1", "item2","item1conditional"],
 description: {
   "ui:widget": "textarea",
   classNames: "foo"
 }
};
```

Make sure you add all items you add in future to this, or it would throw you an error.

Comment: This works in the little example I linked. But in my main application I get a `uiSchema order list contains extraneous property '....'` for conditional code blocks. Have you ran into this before?

Comment: That means that something in the uiSchema is not understood by the library. So it throws the error. Check if all you have declared in uiSchema is defined and if you are using some wildcards make sure you check the library and see its syntaxes

Comment: Yeah, turns out I was using a library which had a dependency on an older version of `rjsf`. Thanks.